# How to convert a string to a numpy matrix? Inverse of numpy.array_str?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string I want to convert to a 2d numpy matrix, i created it by using `numpy.array_str`.

```py
s = '[[ 82.   0.   0.  17.]\n [ 72.   0.   0.  30.]\n [ 79.   0.   0. 131.]\n [ 72.   0.   0.  27.]]'

np.array(s)
np.fromstring(s)
```

However, none of the two methods work. `np.array` just returns the string as a numpy array and `np.fromstring` gives the error message: `string size must be a multiple of element size`.

Got any tips what to do? Is there an "inverse" to `np.array_str`?

Comment: That str format is meant for display, not saving and converting back to array.  You have first to edit the string to make it look like a nested list.

Comment: @hpaulj I understand! What is the recommended way to encode a numpy tensor to a string and the back again?

Comment: Does it have to be a string?  `np.save/load` is the best tool for saving an array to a file,

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to make 2d numpy matrix

```
import numpy as np
s = '[[ 82.   0.   0.  17.]\n [ 72.   0.   0.  30.]\n [ 79.   0.   0. 131.]\n [ 72.   0.   0.  27.]]'
matrix = np.matrix(s)
```

and this will output

```
[[ 82.   0.   0.  17.]
 [ 72.   0.   0.  30.]
 [ 79.   0.   0. 131.]
 [ 72.   0.   0.  27.]]
```

Comment: Thanks! But that is giving the wrong shape, it is (1, 16).